# Dart StreamController().stream equals by == but not by identical

Tags: dart

I found out a confusing Dart `Stream` equality behavior.

```dart
final streamController = StreamController<int>();

final stream1 = streamController.stream;
final stream2 = streamController.stream;

print(stream1 == stream2); // Prints true
print(identical(stream1, stream2)); // Prints false
```

If the `stream2` refers to the `stream1`, it works as expected:

```dart
final streamController = StreamController<int>();

final stream1 = streamController.stream;
final stream2 = stream1;

print(stream1 == stream2); // Prints true
print(identical(stream1, stream2)); // Prints true
```

It all works the same with a `StreamController<int>.broadcast()`. What would be the explanation for this confusing behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `stream` is a getter it can return same object every time but can also create objects for each call like in this case. Take a look at [dart/lib/async/stream_controller.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/53ead360bba7fe4d8f13ff640967974eb3fce271/sdk/lib/async/stream_controller.dart#L495):

```dart
      // Return a new stream every time. The streams are equal, but not identical.
      Stream<T> get stream => _ControllerStream<T>(this);
```

Comment explains this confusing behavior.

Same thing happens in [dart/lib/async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/53ead360bba7fe4d8f13ff640967974eb3fce271/sdk/lib/async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart#L122)

```dart
      Stream<T> get stream => new _BroadcastStream<T>(this);
```

Comment: I see, so this is expected. Not sure if this is desirable...

Comment: @goodonion I took a look into the git history and stopped after I think Dart 0.5 where this behavior was still there. So I think we can conclude it have been like this for at least 10 years. So I don't think too many have thought about this though the times. :)

Comment: The reason for this design is that a `Stream` is just an inert intermediate between the event producer and the event consumer. The moment you call `listen` on the stream, it's no longer important. Instead the stream controller talks directly to the stream subscription, and vice versa.